# way to call - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section without reloading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have done:

`[tableView setNeedsLayout]` and `[tableView setNeedsDisplay]`, however this doesn't call that delegate. Is there a way to re-layout the tableView without reloading the data (i.e: calling reloadData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
//do stuff...
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your need exactly.Then only we can able to help you.

have you did the below steps to initiate delegates of UITableView

1.include UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource 
2.link you tableViewDelegate and datasource to Files Owner in Interface Builder

if you want to call your tableview delegate methods means,

```
[table reloadData]
```

like to know if you need any further clarifications

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of a methods you may use to affect just a part of the table.

Inserting, Deleting, and Moving Rows and Sections:

```
 - (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
 - (void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
 - (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
 - (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
 - (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath;
 - (void)moveSection:(NSInteger)section toSection:(NSInteger)newSection;
```

Reloading:

```
 - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
 - (void)reloadSectionIndexTitles;
 - (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

Don't forget to put your code inside

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
//do stuff...
[tableView endUpdates];
```

block as @Wise Shepherd suggested to avoid incontinence states of the tableView and `index out of bounds` exceptions.